# Proving that a polynomial is irreducible over a field extension of Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose I have the field $ \mathbb Q[\sqrt d] $ where  d is some square free positive integer.

How can I prove that a polynomial with integer coefficients  is irreducible over this field?

And what if the field is something like $ \mathbb Q[\sqrt d_1, \sqrt d_2]$ both $ d_1, d_2$ square free.?

Comment: Do you have any specific polynomial in mind?

Comment: Yeah. Suppose $x^2 - 7$. But I would also like to know some general techniques.

Comment: Yeah.I know. But Eisenstein's crterion is to prove irreducibility over $\mathbb Z$. How do I use it to prove irreducibility over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$?

Comment: I sincerely advice you to read its generalizations present under section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization) and also [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15460/variants-of-eisenstein-irreducibility)

Answer (score 3):

For $x^2-7$, it is easy because it is reducible iff it has a root. Now if $(a+b\sqrt d)^2=7$ then $a^2+b^2 d=7$ and $2ab=0$. If $b=0$, we get $a^2=7$, which is impossible because $\sqrt 7$ is irrational. If $a=0$, we get $b^2 d = 7$ or $u^2 d = 7 v^2$, if $b=u/v$ with $u,v$ coprime integers. Then $v^2$ divides $d$ and so $v^2=1$, because $d$ is square free. This implies that $d=7$ and $u^2=1$.